# make nodejs heroku app do something before become idle

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have nodejs web hosted in heroku. I want to make my app.js do something before going to idle. Like I have a function called prepareIdle(), and i want my app.js called that before going idle. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try listening to the signal `SIGTERM` and do what ever you want within 30 seconds. After 30 seconds, you will receive a `SIGKILL` signal